# IISExpress application pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, appcmd

Is there a way to recycle IIS Express application pool?

If I open cmd and go to `C:\Program Files\IIS Express`, then run:

```
 appcmd apppool /?
```

the list of commands lacks the "recycle" option.

The only workaround I've found is to edit the `applicationhost.config` file. Only then the IISExpress apppool is recycled.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Right click the IIS Express icon in the TaskBar kill all websites and then hit Ctrl-F5 in Visual Studio to restart the Website?

Comment: @Nikolaj Zander The problem with that is that it returns to first page this way. I'm trying to refresh second page. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIS Express does not have application pool support at all, as it is just a single process web server. You can kill the process but it won't automatically start.

True application pool support requires a Windows service like Windows Process Activation Service. Thus, if you do want to test out application pool, use local IIS.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to "simulate" the app pool recycle to test your app initialization routines you could "touch" the `web.config` file too.

Just add a space and re-save.

Comment: Whenever I do this using IIS Express, it causes the debugging app to exit and end the IIS Express session.

Comment: @Fourth for the VS Solution goto Proprieties  > Web  and uncheck Enable Edit and Continue