# Is it possible to recycle IIS EXPRESS application pools without losing user sessions?

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have a similar problem than [Is it possible to recycle IIS application pools without losing user sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277944/is-it-possible-to-recycle-iis-application-pools-without-losing-user-sessions)

I have a web site in dev using IIS Express. 
My session is in a database. 
I search how to recycle the app pool of my site without killing the session.
Its easy on IIS but in IIS Express, I dont know how to recycle without restarting by Visual studio. But when I do that, the session is killed.

Comment: If your session is really in the database, then recycling won't clear them.

Comment: I know, but I dont know HOW TO RECLYCLE IIS EXPRESS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IISExpress application pool recycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718728/iisexpress-application-pool-recycle)

Comment: There is no application pool concept for IIS Express at all, so your question is purely invalid. Simply kill the iisexpress.exe process and start a new one should simulate the actual recycle.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the IIS Express server by right-clicking the icon in the system tray. Relaunching the page from VS will restart it, but IIS Express wasn't meant for anything other than quick page testing and you don't have that level of control with it.

**You can configure your application to NOT use IIS Express and instead use the full IIS in the project's properties. This way, you'll have the full range of features available to you.**

[image]

Comment: I want to do a recycle for keeping the session. a stop or relaunch kill the session.

Comment: recycle and restart are not the same. http://serverfault.com/questions/247425/what-is-the-difference-between-iisreset-recycle-refresh-and-restart